# Center Row in Grid in a Ionic Layout

Tags: ionic-framework, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical center the rows of a grid in a Ionic layout.
I tryed to use css-utilities in this way but it doesn't work:

```
<ion-content>
  <app-auto-logout></app-auto-logout>
   <ion-grid justify-content-center align-items-center style="height: 100%">
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-card text-center padding color="dark" [routerLink]="'/members/recipe'" routerDirection="forward">
          <ion-icon src="/assets/images/notepad.svg" class="home-icon"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-card text-center padding color="dark" [routerLink]="'/drums'" routerDirection="forward">
          <ion-icon src="/assets/images/drum.svg" class="home-icon"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-card text-center padding color="dark" [routerLink]="'/storage'" routerDirection="forward">
          <ion-icon src="/assets/images/storage.svg" class="home-icon"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-card text-center padding color="dark" (click)='openModal()' routerDirection="forward">
          <ion-icon src="/assets/images/warning.svg" class="home-icon"></ion-icon>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks,
Federico.

[EDIT: added screenshot]

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of what you are getting now

Comment: sure, I edited the post